# Reading in XML data from URL using parLapply R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Beginner here, so please alert me to any formatting errors, or general etiquette mistakes.

I am attempting to scrape data from ~800 websites, to increase speed I was looking into running in parallel.

I have simplified my code to produce the error:

```
    url=c("https://apps.hydroshare.org/apps/nwm-forecasts/api/GetWaterML/?config=long_range&geom=channel_rt&variable=streamflow&COMID=6251152&startDate=2018-03-12&lag=t18z&member=4",
          "https://apps.hydroshare.org/apps/nwm-forecasts/api/GetWaterML/?config=long_range&geom=channel_rt&variable=streamflow&COMID=6244518&startDate=2018-03-12&lag=t18z&member=4"
    cores.number=2
    cluster1=makeCluster(cores.number)
    clusterExport(cluster1,"url")
    clusterEvalQ(cluster1,library("xml2"))
    clusterEvalQ(cluster1,url)
    temp=parLapply(cluster1,
              url,
              function(x)
              read_xml(x,fill=TRUE,row.names=NULL))

    stopCluster(cluster1)
```

I get the following error:

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: HTTP error 500.

When doing the same functions with lapply instead of parLapply I have no issues and when I adjust the cores.number to 1 I have no issues.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell us what `b` is?

Comment: Try printing out the URL prior to the `read_xml` call.

Comment: My apologies. B is url. A type when copying over th code. Edited